# Haskell - Blank cells in a sudoku

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, code-formatting

I'm sorry if this EXACT question has already been asked...

I've got a sudoku assignment in Haskell and would appreciate some feedback here.

The goal is to implement a function that represents a Sudoku that contains only blank cells, and then name it `allBlankSudoku :: Sudoku`, where

```
data Sudoku = Sudoku [[Maybe Int]]
```

You should use list comprehensions or the map function to do this,

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This is my take on it:

```
allBlankSudoku :: Sudoku

allBlankSudoku = Sudoku (map (replicate 9) (replicate 9 Nothing))
```

BUT! Here is my question: In the instructions it says "Do not use copy-and-paste programming here! Your definition does not need to be longer than a few short lines."

So, is my code above copy-and-paste or not? Is there an additional way I can do it? Note: This is just the first task out of 3 so I don't think it's supposed to be difficult.

Comment: If you really want, `let r9 = replicate 9 in Sudoku (map r9 (r9 Nothing))`. But this isn't really more readable, nor more efficient.

Comment: Hmm, I put [tag:code-formatting] in but this is more about code practice than code formatting. Is there anybody who knows a good existing tag for this?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I'd tag it "off topic". We are not able to read their teacher's mind any better than they are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reading your teacher's mind.

Comment: @dfeuer I disagree, copy paste programming is a well known term among programmers. Language is a method of conveying what's on somebody's mind, and in this case we are better in reading the teachers mind than a non-experienced programmer. Besides that "is this copy-paste programming" seems to be a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy-and-paste programming here probably means that your professor doesn't want:

```
allBlank = Sudoku [[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing ... ]
                  ,[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing ...
                  ...
                  ]
```

By the way, as a minor note, I think

```
allBlank = Sudoku (replicate 9 (replicate 9 Nothing))
```

is a little easier to understand for me :)

If you *need* to use list comprehensions, you can do:

```
[ [ Nothing | x <- [1..9] ] | y <- [1..9] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

No that's not copy-and-paste, you let your program do the copy-paste here. Copy-paste code is about repeating lines or blocks of *source code*. Such as `cell_0_0 = nothing`, `cell_0_1 = nothing` etc. Actually, your code looks quite succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-and-paste programming would be when you copy one line of code and paste it multiple times to do the same thing.
Recursion is the way to go.